# eacces error in RabbitMQ when trying to set up federation

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, fedora, federation

I'm trying to prototype federated message queuing between a Mac host and a Fedora 20 image running under VirtualBox.  After a certain amount of head banging I managed to get the Mac exchanges federated from the Fedora exchanges, meaning that messages sent to the Fedora upstream broker are received on the Mac broker.

However, when trying to go the other way (Fedora sees Mac as upstream), I get error messages about "eacces".

```
==> rabbit@localhost.log <==

=WARNING REPORT==== 29-Jan-2014::21:18:11 ===
Federation exchange 'amq.direct' in vhost '/' did not connect to exchange 'amq.direct' in vhost '/' on amqp://172.30.42.19
{error,eacces}

==> rabbit@localhost-sasl.log <==

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 29-Jan-2014::21:18:11 ===
 Supervisor: {<0.15681.0>,
                                       rabbit_federation_link_sup}
 Context:    child_terminated
 Reason:     {shutdown,restart}
 Offender:   [{pid,<0.21716.0>},
              {name,
                  {upstream,
                      [<<"amqp://guest:guest@172.30.42.19">>],
                      <<"amq.direct">>,<<"amq.direct">>,1000,1,1,36000000,
                      none,false,'on-confirm',none,<<"mac_host">>}},
              {mfargs,
                  {rabbit_federation_exchange_link,start_link,
                      [{{upstream,
                            [<<"amqp://guest:guest@172.30.42.19">>],
                            <<"amq.direct">>,<<"amq.direct">>,1000,1,1,
                            36000000,none,false,'on-confirm',none,
                            <<"mac_host">>},
                        {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"amq.direct">>}}]}},
              {restart_type,{permanent,1}},
              {shutdown,4294967295},
              {child_type,worker}]
```

My Google-fu is failing me.  What may be causing the above error and how should I go about fixing it?

BTW, on the theory that it might be the Linux or Mac firewalls, I tried opening a browser on the Fedora box and requesting `http://172.30.42.19:5672`.  I got a (tiny) answer in return, so the firewall looks less likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may well be related to SELinux settings. When I disabled SELinux, this error went away and RabbitMQ started working as expected.

The following command can be used to disable SELinux on Fedora 20: `sudo setenforce 0`

Comment: This bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=998682 may be related to this problem.